# Creating preprocessor function before Input

Tags: node.js, express

I have a game server that input works on demand. Someone else wrote it, but hadn't finished before leaving company, and I have to built it up now.
The guy forgot to do some basic things like (checking multiloging, decoding variables etc).
It has a lot of functions, and it would take week to rebuild them.

```
app.post('/productionFarm', function(req, res) {
(...)
app.post('/skipProductionFarm') {
(...)
//and about 200 more
```

Do you know any good solution, how to do preprocessor function (one function for all inputs), that on post Input will do some code first, then will continue or not doing app.post queries?.

Comment: Looks like express: http://expressjs.com/

Comment: Yeah it's made in expressjs.

Comment: Then start reading the docs, I don't really get what you are asking for. `app.post` doesn't do a query, it registers a resource.

Comment: I want to add security to this code. And my idea is to add to every I/O function, function that is checking things, but it will take time so my question was, if I can just put one function for all inputs, that will check something. I'v wrote few servers in node.js, but I was thinking about security from start. Now I have unsecure inputs, that I have to secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to run a function prior to any POST routes. This is pretty simple using a middleware:

```
app.post('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    if(checkInputs(req)) {
        // check successful
        next();
    } else {
         // either handle the error directly
         res.send(400, 'Bad request');
         // or use a separate error handling middleware
         next(new Error('Bad request'));
    }
});
```

Note that this must come before any of your `app.post` calls.

http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.use